# Generating EC2 launch template from running EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to generate a launch template from a running EC2 instance into JSON file 
any idea how to generate such a template using "aws ec2" CLI?

Thanks

Comment: What if you create AMI and lunch instnace from that AMI

Answer (score 0):

There is no command available to convert a running Amazon EC2 instance into a launch template.

It is *possible* to code this functionality, as demonstrated by the **Launch More Like This** command in the console (which does multiple functions to achieve this, rather than calling a single API call). However, you would have to code it yourself.